# Calculate Sum of Zabbix items

Tags: snmp, zabbix

I want to monitor a switch (48 ports).

With SNMP and LDD, i can have the bandwidth of each port, but i want to have the sum of all items (something like ifOutOctets(*))

Is is possible ? How ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently not possible, but you might wish to vote and follow on [ZBXNEXT-1420](https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBXNEXT-1420).